# Can lots of tags affect performance?

Tags: taxonomy, performance, optimization

I'm working on a plugin that will auto-tag my posts (it's for a very specific, single project only). It will apply 6 tags based on the content of the post.

Forward thinking, I wonder if the number of tags that will build over time will eventually begin to affect performance?

I am doing it to add a bit more "width" to my index as to assist my related posts section with actually linking to related posts. :)

If the site builds to thousands of tags will there be a noticeable effect? I don't know WordPress well enough to know if there are subroutines using the wp_terms and wp_termmeta tables heavily.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably yes. Even if you don't know about WP in depth, you can always create a test project. Create 1000 posts. Copy it, create alot of tags to these posts, run the functions ("get related posts") and see how performance differs

Comment: @kero That's a good point. I can spin up a test site for it. I am curious if someone has experience doing this on a live site while 500+ concurrent users browse the site.

Comment: For large websites, you have alot of other stuff to worry about. Short answer: caching

Comment: Oh yea, absolutely. My site is very well cached. I don't personally think there will be a problem. Just looking ahead just in case. Thank you.